# Estimated 13.77 billion years is this age of observable universe or the entire universe?

Tags: history

Can we calculate the age of entire universe not just the observable part ? If any type of EMW will never reach earth how can we ever know ?

Comment: There will be no observations or measurements of the non observable universe, only theories.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the age of the observable universe. I think it's possible to make accurate predictions about the age of the unobservable universe if it turns out to be spatially finite.

Comment: Answered here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/why-is-the-observable-universe-larger-than-its-age-would-suggest

Comment: This is an interesting question but I feel that it is off-topic here in *Space Exploration* SE. There is some significant overlap with this site and [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) but for topics like cosmology it won't "fly" here. Nonetheless, *welcome to Space!*